# Effective way to allocate and delete memory using smart pointer in C++

Tags: c++, boost

I have function `some_func_1` which will create an object of type `some_type` and will return pointer to memory allocated for this object.

This memory must be deleted using special `some_func_2`. It is possible to use `boost::shared_ptr<some_type>` and specify `some_func_2` as custom delete function, but it is not effective way, because I have only one thread and there is only one user of allocated memory.

In other words I need some thing like `scoped_ptr`, but with possibility of defining custom deallocation function. How to do this with maximum effectiveness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) (which is available with C++11).

*However*, what efficiency problems are you talking about ? Is it that you don't want to have a reference-counted pointer when you know you will only have one instance of the pointer ?

If so, don't worry to much about that: sure the reference counting here seems a bit useless, but shouldn't cause much performance issues. Have you profiled your code to be sure that it was problematic ?

Unless you run under particularly low memory conditions or in a context where every processor cycle matters, I highly doubt you will even notice the difference.

**Write maintainable code first**, then, if you encounter performance issues, profile and optimize. Doing it the other way around is a waste of time.

Comment: yes I don't want to make extra operations, in this case reference counting. I will use this code in while loop, something like, `while(true){ //allocate memory for object, use it, ...  }`

Comment: What about using `BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT`?

Comment: @akmal: The overhead caused by the use of `shared_ptr` is probably so minimal that I seriously doubt it can cause a performance issue compared to the time taken by the memory allocation itself. Anyway, before you notice a real and measurable performance issue, don't second guess and go for `shared_ptr` :)

Answer (score 1):

`boost::scoped_ptr` designers didn't want to support custom deallocator to reduce any possible overhead. To quote the [boost mailing group](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2003/04/46483.php):

> If you want a shared_ptr-style runtime custom deallocator support,
>   this is  not supported because the overhead was (and is) considered
>   unacceptable for  scoped_ptr. Use shared_ptr instead.

In C++11 [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) can call custom deallocator. You have to pass the function object or lvalue reference to function or to function object as a second parameter of `std::unique_ptr` template.

Comment: I recommend switching to C++11, because there are many useful things, but I've found that unique_ptr lives in `boost::interprocess`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/unique_ptr.html

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to encapsulate **some_type** in **another_type**, use any smart pointer you like and have the destructor of another_type handle the deallocation of some_type.